# differences and advantages of Response.Write and MsgBox

Tags: vbscript

I have been trying to build a website implementing a VBscript and I have been finding almost a 50/50 split on these two methods for display text on the page.

```
Response.Write("Hello World")
MsgBox("Hello World")
```

What I have found is MSgBox displays a MessageBox and returns a value when the user clicks on a button. That explanation was given of the w3schools website.

Response.Write just seems to have examples of how to use it no real explanation. Is this equivalent to the System.out.println(); I am familar with from Java?

What is the difference between these two and what are each ones advantages? Could either of these be used as a link to another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Msgbox as you say simply displays a prompt to the user, although it only returns a value on certain types of msg prompts for example, Yes/No.

Response.Write is there to print information straight to the page.

As both are used for different purposes, I wouldn't really compare them in as much as one would offer advantages over the other, use whichever is best fit for the purpose.

As for usage with a link, neither on their own are capable of the action, although you could use Response.Write to print a hyperlink address on to the page.